# What is the correct approach for denying access to specific resources in spring MVC + security

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I've seen many questions requesting how to handle security scenarios, all either have solutions for method annotations (i.e. `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")`) or using a point-cut.

However what if the resource isn't known if the user has access until the resource has been read from a data store? Let's consider a user who has access to a set of customers, the rest endpoint for these customers can be found at `/customers/{id}`. A user is only allowed access if they have been granted access to read the account, likewise they must also have access to make a `POST` to the same endpoint.

One way would be:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/customers/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView customerPage(String id, HttpServletRequest req, Principal principal) {
    if (!req.isUserInRole("ROLE_ADMIN") && !cs.accessGranted(id, principal.getName())) {
        throw new AccessDeniedException("You do not have access to view this custoemr.");
    }
    Customer cust = cs.getCustomer(id);
    if (cust == null) {
        throw new ResourceNotFoundException("Customer does not exist!");
    }
    ModelAndView mov = new ModelAndView("customers/info");
    mov.addObject("customer", cust);
    return mov;
}
```

I'm wondering if this is the right approach though.

**UPDATE**: Call to `accessGranted` was meant to have `id` as an argument which I missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to continue use `@PreAuthorize` annotations. You can call beans directly from SpEL expression:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER') and !@cs.accessGranted(#principal.getName())")
public ModelAndView customerPage(String id, HttpServletRequest req, Principal principal) {
```

`@cs` refers to bean id = "cs" declared somwhere in your application context. Later you can future simplify it by removing `Principal principal` method parameter and getting username directly in SpEL.

If your find yourself using this tehnique often then check out [Spring Security ACL](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/domain-acls.html) module.

Comment: That's a great approach, I would in fact prefer the SpEL to refer to instance members for the service so that I don't need to name my service beans, though I think your solution is the most flexible.

Comment: Good idea. How you can get reference members? Using `#root` variable?

Comment: I think it's actually `#this`, but I believe you can't access the members but can access accessor. I haven't tried it but `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') or !#this.accessGranted(#id, #principal.getName())")`. I think also that `#principal` is available automatically in spring security expressions. I've never really used SpEL and I couldn't get the annotations to work even though I turned it all on, they seemed to get ignored.

Comment: Check [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/faq.html#faq-method-security-in-web-context) FAQ entry

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense now; though I will not be messing with my contexts at this point in time to try and get them secured via annotations, I won't be securing my service layer as that doesn't depend on Spring, so that's also not an option, plus, my services shouldn't be bound to security anyway. Something to think about later I suppose :) What I've done in my original question will have to suffice for now.

Answer (score 0):

My favorite way is to use the [@Secured](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/annotation/Secured.html) annotation on a method, which takes an array of Strings representing the Role(s) required to execute the method.  I like this method because you are not limited to putting security only on URL patterns.  For instance, you can add this to a method in your Service class, and any Controller using that Service is now secured.

The other common method is to include URL filters in the Spring Security XML file.  I forget the exact syntax, but you basically setup filters that match a URL and indicate what Role(s) are needed.

Comment: This does not protect specific domain objects though, it will protect a method or URI. I need for example `/customers/123` to be accessible by user `jdoe` but `/customers/234` should not be accessible. It is a security ACL that determines what user has access to what customer(s).

Comment: I don't think there is an out-of-box solution for this.  I think you will need to develop custom code to handle this.